# how can I assign a variable to hold an image in php

Tags: php

I was just wondering if I could have a variable to hold an image, I'm using phpmailer to send email and I need an image to be attached to it,

so I was wondering if I could put the image in a variable and use

```
$mailer->AddAttachment($image);
```

to send the email with attachment.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess $image should contain local path to the image file.

If you look at phpMailer source, at line 1218:
http://phpmailer.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/phpmailer/phpmailer/trunk/class.phpmailer.php?revision=444&view=markup
you'll see that it verifies at first that what you have given is path to existing file. There is no other option.

Answer (score 1):

With PhpMailer adding an attachment is done the way you wrote it in the question

```
$mailer->AddAttachment('/home/mywebsite/file.jpg', 'file.jpg');
```

If you want to use a variable you can change the string by a variable without problem.

```
$imagePath = '/home/mywebsite/file.jpg';
imageName = 'file.jpg'
$mailer->AddAttachment($imagePath, $imageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, that's exactly how it's supposed to be used.

According [to this document](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html), you'd do something like this:

```
$myImg = '/some/path/to/image.jpg';
$mailer->AddAttachment($myImg);
```

Is that not what you're trying?

Comment: yes that's what I did and I was getting errors so I thought maybe I'm doing sth wrong.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you do this this way? [Sending email attachments in PHP Using phpmailer class !](http://zainal.wordpress.com/2007/01/10/sending-email-attachments-in-php-using-phpmailer-class/)